# Enable remote access to web site

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, windows-sbs-2008

First of all, I would like to state that I'm a complete newbie if it comes to server management, so please don't hate me if I ask something that might be very obvious.

Where I work, we have a server that hold all files and hosts a website for remote mail access which is "remote.mycompany.com". The dns is set up so that the default website being "mycompany.com" / "www.mycompany.com" points to an external ip, which is the server of the hosting company that manages our website. Both of these work fine.

As of now, I was asked to create a small website for remote access of some data in our SQL database. For this, I created a new website in IIS, and configured the dns with the address "data.mycompany.com".

This is where I'm getting in trouble. When use my browser and go to "data.mycompany.com" using a computer here at the company, everything works as it should. However when I try connecting from my phone through the mobile network (not WiFi), I get redirected to the main page of the hosting company's server ("mycompany.com" loads our website, not the hosts server main page).

In Windows SBS Console under Network > Connectivity, I can see "remote.mycompany.com" listed under Internet Domain Name, "data.mycompany.com" however isn't.

The firewall runs on an external system, could this be a place to look for something to resolve this issue?

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create a DNS record in your "public" DNS for data.company.com that points to the ip address of your internal web server.

Comment: What do you mean with "public"? On the server's DNS Manager I added a new Host (A) named "DATA" in the "mycompany.com" zone, because there was one named "REMOTE" there too. The firewall however is handled on using an external system, should I configure something there? When I look in Windows SBS Console under Network > Connectivity, "remote.mycompany.com" is listed there, but "data.mycompany.com" isnt

Comment: You have an internal DNS server that handles the internal company.com DNS zone and you have an external DNS server that handles the external company.com DNS zone. The external DNS server is probably either with your domain registrar or your web hosting company. In order to resolve data.mycompany.com from the outside you need to have a DNS record in the external DNS server that "maps" data.mycompany.com to the ip address of your internal web server, most likely the NAT'ed ip address.

Comment: Allright, I'll have to check where the domain is handled, I'm guessing the hosting company. Thanks for the information!